# How to Deploy .Net 6 Application to Server from Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab, plesk

I have a gitlab repo that builds a Net 6 application. I have Plesk on my server (interserver) and am a bit confused on how to actually send the build over to plesk or even my server. Here is my yml file

How on earth do I send the actual application to my folder on the server which exists at this location: ./dev.myworkatcornerstone.com

```
# To contribute improvements to CI/CD templates, please follow the Development guide at:
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/cicd/templates.html
# This specific template is located at:
# https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/dotNET-Core.yml

# This is a simple example illustrating how to build and test .NET Core project
# with GitLab Continuous Integration / Continuous Delivery.
#
# ### Specify the Docker image
#
# Instead of installing .NET Core SDK manually, a docker image is used
# with already pre-installed .NET Core SDK.
#
# The 'latest' tag targets the latest available version of .NET Core SDK image.
# If preferred, you can explicitly specify version of .NET Core (e.g. using '2.2-sdk' tag).
#
# See other available tags for .NET Core: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet
# Learn more about Docker tags: https://docs.docker.com/glossary/?term=tag
# and the Docker itself: https://opensource.com/resources/what-docker
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0

stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deploy

# ### Define variables
#
variables:
  # 1) Name of directory where restore and build objects are stored.
  OBJECTS_DIRECTORY: 'obj'
  # 2) Name of directory used for keeping restored dependencies.
  NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY: '.nuget'
  # 3) A relative path to the source code from project repository root.
  # NOTE: Please edit this path so it matches the structure of your project!
  SOURCE_CODE_PATH: '/builds/DavidML3/cornerstone_staff_api' 
  PUBLISHDIR: $SOURCE_CODE_PATH/bin/Release/net6.0/publish
  isPullRequest: $[eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')]
  isDevelopment: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')]
  USERNAME_DEV: 'WebAdmin'
  PASSWORD_DEV:  'password'
  DEPLOYSERVER_DEV: 'ipaddress'
  FTP_DESTINATION: 'dev.myworkatcornerstone.com/App_Data/'


  

# ### Define global cache rule
#
# Before building the project, all dependencies (e.g. third-party NuGet packages)
# must be restored. Jobs on GitLab.com's Shared Runners are executed on autoscaled machines.
#
# Each machine is used only once (for security reasons) and after that is removed.
# This means that, before every job, a dependency restore must be performed
# because restored dependencies are removed along with machines. Fortunately,
# GitLab provides cache mechanism with the aim of keeping restored dependencies
# for other jobs.
#
# This example shows how to configure cache to pass over restored
# dependencies for re-use.
#
# With global cache rule, cached dependencies will be downloaded before every job
# and then unpacked to the paths as specified below.
cache:
  # Per-stage and per-branch caching.
  key: "$CI_JOB_STAGE-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
  paths:
    # Specify three paths that should be cached:
    #
    # 1) Main JSON file holding information about package dependency tree, packages versions,
    # frameworks etc. It also holds information where to the dependencies were restored.
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH/$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/project.assets.json'
    # 2) Other NuGet and MSBuild related files. Also needed.
    - '$SOURCE_CODE_PATH/$OBJECTS_DIRECTORY/*.csproj.nuget.*'
    # 3) Path to the directory where restored dependencies are kept.
    - '$NUGET_PACKAGES_DIRECTORY'
  #
  # 'pull-push' policy means that latest cache will be downloaded (if it exists)
  # before executing the job, and a newer version will be uploaded afterwards.
  # Such a setting saves time when there are no changes in referenced third-party
  # packages.
  #
  # For example, if you run a pipeline with changes in your code,
  # but with no changes within third-party packages which your project is using,
  # then project restore will happen quickly as all required dependencies
  # will already be there — unzipped from cache.

  # 'pull-push' policy is the default cache policy, you do not have to specify it explicitly.
  policy: pull-push

build:
  stage: build
  # ### Build all projects discovered from solution file.
  #
  # Note: this will fail if you have any projects in your solution that are not
  # .NET Core-based projects (e.g. WCF service), which is based on .NET Framework,
  # not .NET Core. In this scenario, you will need to build every .NET Core-based
  # project by explicitly specifying a relative path to the directory
  # where it is located (e.g. 'dotnet build ./src/ConsoleApp').
  # Only one project path can be passed as a parameter to 'dotnet build' command.
  script:
    - 'dotnet build'

test:
    stage: test
    script: 
        - "dotnet test"

deploy:
  stage: deploy  
  only:
    - Development
  environment:
    Development
  artifacts:
        paths:
            - $SOURCE_CODE_PATH/bin/release/net6.0/publish
        expire_in: 1 week    
  script: 
    - pwd ls -la     
    - cd $SOURCE_CODE_PATH  
    - dotnet publish -c release
    - echo "*****Install lftp*****"
    - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq zip lftp
    - cd $PUBLISHDIR
    - echo "*****Upload file to ftp*****"    
    - pwd ls -la find /build.
    #- lftp -e "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $USERNAME_DEV,$PASSWORD_DEV $DEPLOYSERVER_DEV;mirror -R ./  ./$FTP_DESTINATION;"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your deploy section. This worked for me when I was using gitlab to deploy and angular application to plesk. This will delete all of the files on the server first then copy the files from your dist folder over to the server

```
- cd $ProjectDir
      - npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
      - npm install
      - npm run build-prod
      - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
      - lftp -e "set ssl:verify-certificate no; open $DEPLOYSERVER_DEV; user $USERNAME_DEV $PASSWORD_DEV; mirror -p -X .* -X .*/ --reverse --verbose --delete ./dist ./httpdocs; bye"
      - echo "deployment complete"
```